# Keeping 3 cards in same row using grid

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, grid-layout

I created a list of cards using grid. The CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.grid > article {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.grid > article img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid .text {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        <article v-for="tool in tools">
            <div class="title">
                <h3>{{capitalizeFirstLetter(tool.name)}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                {{tool.description}}
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I keep up to 3 cards per row? I can't seem to understand how should I treat the grid so I will keep maximum 3 cards per row. For example I have 8 elements, then It will be:

```
card card card
card card card
card card
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `grid-template-columns` property `auto-fill` to `3`.

```css
body {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(280px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.grid>article {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.grid>article img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid .text {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <article>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if the window is small it will keep three elements in that row. I need maximum three elements. If the windows is smaller it will keep one/two.

Comment: @vesii It behave achieve Media Queries.

Comment: what do you mean? with `auto-fill` it will keep with the windows size. Is it possible `auto-fill` with maximum `3` elements in row?

Comment: @vesii `auto-fill` and its behavior cannot coexist. Use media query example : https://jsfiddle.net/kn67sa0p

Comment: @vesii This fiddle css fixes the maximum number of columns to 3 lines on a large screen size.